# Emacs display inline suggestions

Tags: emacs, emacs24

My Emacs configuration used to have a functionality where if I would call, for instance, `M-x` or `find-file` it would display inline suggestions as:

```
M-x [ align-regexp | auto-fill-mode | ... ]
```

But when I updated the Prelude the other day, this functionality disappeared. To my shame, I have to admit I don't know what this functionality is called, or how to reactivate it.

I'm running Emacs24 with the [Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude).

Comment: I'm not sure why it would have stopped working, but this was likely provided by Prelude's [`ido` / `smex` configuration](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/modules/prelude-ido.el). Does `(require 'prelude-ido)` reactivate it?

Comment: See also library `icomplete.el`.  That too gives you this information, without changing the basic minibuffer interaction as does ido.

Comment: An information if you like inline suggestions: ever heard of the (incoming) `discover` package ? http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/12/21/discoverel-discover-emacs-context-menus/ it sounds very promising to me and is already working for some modes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Prelude's author. The functionality you describe comes from the `smex` package, that's enabled in `prelude-ido.el`. Some time ago `ido` support was moved out of the default configuration into a separate module (so people that don't use ido and its related packages could disable it easily) and I guess that's what's causing your problem. You probably don't have `prelude-ido` enabled in your `prelude-modules.el`.